# Does the book "Algebra III" exist (within the Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences series from Springer)?

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, books

Within the series "Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences", as published by Springer, one finds the 8 volumes, namely,
the volumes I, II, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX but zbMath has no listing for a
volume III, so my surmise is that it was never published. Anyone know the history of this subseries?

Comment: these volumes appeared originally in Russian; they are listed [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?jrnid=intf&wshow=contents&option_lang=rus) -- searching for "алгебра" gives volume 1 (published in 1986, series volume 11), volume 2 (published in 1988, series volume 18) and then volumes 4 and 5 (published in 1989, series volumes 37 and 38); so evidently volume 3 was missing from the start -- presumably some author who did not deliver...

Comment: yes. zbMath .  Thanks @CarloBeenakker for the response.